# SSIS 2008 R2 - How to convert a NText stream to string

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 SSIS

I have a column which is a DT_NText Stream (Unicode Text Stream)

Is there an easy way that I can convert this into a string?

Answer (score 0):

[Data Conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141706.aspx) Task?

Maybe I'm missing something...there's no data conversion matrix on this page.

Comment: Actually run it through two data conversions in the Data Conversion task.